# Spring Boot entity not being recognized during build

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, maven, spring-data-jpa, entity

I'm running into this error when I `mvn clean install` my Spring Boot application:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.fitzgerald.floorplanmanager.data.Users
```

I've tried adding `@EntityScan` to my Application class, with and without a defined pathname, but to no avail.
I also have two other Entities aside from `Users`.  I'm not sure if they are being recognized or if `Users` was just the first entity that the compiler encountered (my gut says the latter), but I'm not seeing them in the stacktrace.
Here is what my Application class looks like:

```
@EntityScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class FloorplanmanagerApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(FloorplanmanagerApplication.class, args);
   }

}
```

This is my `UsersRepository`:

```
@Transactional
public interface UsersRepository extends CrudRepository<Users, Long> {

}
```

`UsersService`:

```
@Service
public class UsersServiceImpl implements UsersService {

    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @Override
    public Users saveUsers(Users users) {
        return usersRepository.save(users);
    }
}
```

and finally `Users`:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "users")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Users {

    @Id
    @Column
    private long id;
    @Column
    private String userName;
    @Column
    private String password;
}
```

[My file structure looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncaId.png)
Also, my `data.sql` file in `com.fitzgerald.floorplanmanager.resources` looks like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;

CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    USER_NAME VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    PASSWORD VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
);

// two more tables are created...
```

I've tried using the folder name `entity` instead of `data`, adding `@EntityScan("com.fitzgerald.floorplanmanager.data")` to the Application class, adding `@EnableJpaRepositories`, `@ComponentScan`, and messing with the file structure but I just can't get it to work.
Thanks!

Comment: How does your package structure looks like? If the application class is in the tree above everything else you don't have to configure anything

Comment: Yes, it's in the dir above everything else.  A screenshot can be found in the answer